# How to change the format of output for an angle

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method that determines the form of an angle (either radians or degrees) and from there, when prompted changes the format that the angle is displayed. The class starts in degrees but I can't find a way to get it to change to radians based on the input from the simulation class that I made.

```
public static boolean type(String[] args)
{   
    MyVector vec1 = new MyVector(2,3);
    MyVector vec2 = new MyVector(-1,4);
    if(vec1.angle(vec2) == 47.7263){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far to determine whether or not the class is operating in degrees or radians but after this, I have no clue what to do. I thought about adding some type of counter to the simulation class to see how many times the method to change the class was run but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: What are you expecting from `args`? Looking at your function now, seems it is not used!!

Comment: Not completely sure what it does, just thought it had to be there.

Comment: You say absolutely nothing about how your algorithm is meant to work. Are we meant to guess?